# How can I import functions that change the state of my functional component (Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component whose state is maintained by hooks using use State. This component actually uses a lot of functions and I want to store such functions in another file and import it. Some of these functions use variables initialized in my functional component and changes the state. How can I achieve this functionality while maintaining modularity.

Here's my code. Sorry if it's long.Errors I'm getting- React is saying that the variables I'm attempting to reference instantiated in my functional component are undefined.

I am importing from NQueensSolution file

**MY FUNCTIONAL COMPONENT**

```
import React, { isValidElement, useState } from 'react'
import Board from './Board';
import './../styling/NQueens.css'
import *  as Solution from './../Solutions/NQueensSolution';


export default function NQueens(){
var rowSet = [];
var colSet = [];
var dx = [-1,1,1,-1];//Direction vectors for checking diagonals, goes NE, SE, SW, NW respectively
var dy = [1,1,-1,-1]; 
const [board, setBoard] = useState([]);  //Our board
const [n, setN] = useState(1);
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
const [solutions, setSolutions] = useState([]); //Stores all of our solutions to display in the end!



const  dimHandler = (e) =>{   // const means you can change this function 
    setN( e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);
}

const generateHandler = (e) => {  //Generate the nxn board,
    e.preventDefault();  // By default, when pressing a button, the page refreshes, this prevents it
    console.log("This is n" + n);

    rowSet = new Array(n);  //Initialize row buckets
    colSet = new Array(n); //Initialize colBuckets

    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        rowSet[i] = false;
        colSet[i] = false;
    }

    let row = []; 
    let newBoard = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        row.push('-');
    }
    for( let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        newBoard.push(row);
    }
    setBoard( newBoard );
    setActive(true);
    console.log(board);
    
}


    return (
        <div>
            <form>
            <label>Dimension Of Board:
            <input type = "number" name = "dimension" min = "1" max = "8" onChange = {dimHandler} />
            <button onClick = { generateHandler}>Generate</button>
            </label>
            </form>
            {active === true? <Board className = "BoardContainer" board = {board} n = {n} /> : null  /*Let's generate the board */ } 

            <button onClick = {Solution.solveHandler}>Solve</button>
            
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here's my file that contains functions I want to import and use in my functional component

```
 export {cache, deCache, isValidBounds, canPlace, backTrack,solveHandler};

 const cache = (x,y) => {
     rowSet[x] = true;
     colSet[y] = true;
 }
 const deCache = (x,y) =>{
     rowSet[x] = false;
     colSet[y] = false;
 }

 const isValidBounds = (x,y) =>{ //used to check diagonal bounds
 if(x < 0 || x >=n || y < 0 || y>= n ) return false;
 return true;
  }

 const canPlace = (x,y) => {   //essentially valid bounds

if( xSet[x] || ySet[y]) return false;  //Is the row/column occupied?
let xTemp,yTemp;
for( let i = 0 ; i < 4 ;i++){ //Check diagonals
    xTemp = dx[i];
    yTemp = dy[i];
    while( isValidBounds(xTemp,yTemp)){
        if(board[xTemp][yTemp] == 'Q') return false;
        xTemp += dx[i];
        yTemp += dy[i];
    }
} 
return true;
 }


 const backTrack = ( row ) => {

if( row == n ){  //we've found a solution, just return to false to continue our search
    solutions.push(board);
    return false;
}
for( let i = 0; i< n ; i++){
    if(canPlace(x,y)){
        board[row][i] = 'Q';
        cache(row,i);
        if(!backTrack(row + 1)){  //It means our assumption that we had a valid board failed, backtrack
            board[row][i] = '-';  //set it back to empty
            deCache(row,i);
        }
    }
    
}

return false; //We've exhausted all possible placements for our assumption backtrack!!!
}


const solveHandler = () =>{
backTrack(0);
}
```

Comment: I suggest [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html). It is not clear to me if you also have a problem with the local variables (e.g. `rowSet`, `colSet`), you have them in your example code, but didn't mention them in your question, but that's plain JS, so I think no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the post, but I believe it is doable if you use function declarations instead of arrow functions. The way I've seen them used to change state is to use both functions (example: cache and setBoard) in an async/await in your functional component so you can pass arguments through.